# Unable to connect two machines through an Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, routing, ethernet, ipv4

I have 2 Ubuntu machines, connected via Ethernet cable, machine A at interface eth0 and machine B at eth6. I have configured IP on both machine.

ifconfig -a on machine A (showing for eth0 only):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:90:96:9b:83:f1  
          inet addr:100.0.2.1  Bcast:100.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9a90:96ff:fe9b:83f1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:101005 (101.0 KB)  TX bytes:30148 (30.1 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000
```

route -n on Machine A:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         203.135.63.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth3
100.0.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth3
203.135.63.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     1      0        0 eth3
```

ifconfig -a on Machine B (Showing for eth6 only)

```
eth6      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:08:6b:0b:85:72  
          inet addr:100.0.2.3  Bcast:100.0.2.225  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ee08:6bff:fe0b:8572/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:90 (90.0 B)
```

route -n on machine B:

```
Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask        Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.102.72.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth7
10.102.72.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     1      0        0 eth7
100.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
100.0.2.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

When I ping 100.0.2.1 from machine B, I get this:

```
PING 100.0.2.1 (100.0.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 100.0.2.3 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 100.0.2.1 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, +9 errors, 100% packet loss, time 10054ms
pipe 3
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you using `100.0.0.0/8` for your internal network? You're squatting on Verizon's IP space, as well as Sprint's, Amazon EC2's, T-Mobile's, &c… The only reserved "private use" space in that region is actually `100.64.0.0/10` with netmask `255.192.0.0`. That is of course, unless you meant `10.0.0.0/8` (one zero).

Comment: You should be using a [crossover Ethernet cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). Are you?

Comment: @harrymc: [Should you?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/28204/3955) Crossover cables are generally a thing of the past now.

Comment: The first thing that stands out are the overlapping routes on machine B (100.*.*.*/8 on eth0), on top of eth0 having a link-local address.  You didn't say what's behind eth0 there, but remove this route, and see if the ping then works. Also use `ip route get 100.0.2.1` on B to test if routing is correct. And while you are at it, change the `100.*.*.*` IP range to a proper private IP range, e.g. `10.*.*.*/8` and `10.0.2.*/24`, as the other comment said.

Comment: Investigating with `ip route get` is a good idea, but generally routes are longest-prefix-match so it would be very curious if that were the problem. (Indeed most computers have 2–3 overlapping routes anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason for such a problem is that you are not using a
[crossover Ethernet cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable)
or a crossover adapter.

[[image: Gigabit Ethernet crossover cable ends]Gigabit Ethernet crossover cable ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKZOI.jpg)

[[image: 8P8C modular crossover adapter]8P8C modular crossover adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPaWS.jpg)

Comment: This seems unlikely given the nearly ubiquitous prevalence of auto-MDIX NICs.

Comment: This was the issue, I had connected one end of the crossover cable it to a USB port via TP-LINK Ethernet Adapter, which didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: @RamzahRehman You already had a crossover cable, and it wasn't working?

Comment: @Xen2050 Believe it or not, there are some media access controllers out there that technically implement MDI-X, but don't work correctly if there is a crossover cable involved.  I've not seen one in quite a while, and I've never seen a Gigabit one, but a handful of older computers I've dealt with that had 100BaseT cards had the same issues.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That's what it sounded like... OP already tried a crossover cable and it was not working, but if true then why would he pick this answer as the correct one? It's the opposite of what solved the problem...?

Comment: @Xen2050 I had a crossover cable but I had not plugged it in crossover adapter, I had plugged it in a USB adapter, not a 8P8C modular crossover adapter. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: @RamzahRehman But using a crossover cable *together* with a crossover adapter... that just turns it back into a regular (patch) cable